# GoogleTest: how to return success result?

Tags: c++, googletest

In the documentation of GoogleTest I found this:

`SUCCEED();`

*Generates a success. This does NOT make the overall test succeed. A test is considered successful only if none of its assertions fail during its execution.*

Does this mean unless an assertion fails, there's no way to end a test early?

Comment: What happens if you `return` right after the `SUCCEED();`?

Comment: @Blaze the simplest solution didn't cross my mind.. that works Edit: making up for my name, I guess

Comment: The documentation also states (emphasis mine): "Note: `SUCCEED()` **is purely documentary** and currently doesn't generate any user-visible output. However, we may add `SUCCEED()` messages to Google Test's output in the future." So, yeah, `return` is your best choice.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Please don't answer in comments.  Make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Test defines "success" as "no failures".

(So, simply returning is sufficient.)